# Unable to Acquire the State Change Lock

Tags: java, osgi, eclipse-luna

Our products are using the latest production-ready release of SWT, 3.7.2. Now since no one back then knew what the next Java version would be called (and how would they know that 8 came after 7, that's like higher mathematics), we were forced to swap the `org.eclipse.osgi` from 3.7.2 to 3.10.0, so that we can now support Java 8. While that's maybe not the best of ideas, in theory it *should* work.

Of course, being the major screw-up that Eclipse Luna is, there is this one "error" when we start our applications (about 50 percent of the time, I'd guess):

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to acquire the state change lock for the module: osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.osgi"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.10.0.v20140606-1445"; singleton:="true" [id=0] STARTED [STARTED] invalid
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.lockStateChange(Module.java:329)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.init(SystemModule.java:44)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.start(SystemModule.java:170)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:393)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:412)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.ConfigApplier.startBundles(ConfigApplier.java:307)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.ConfigApplier.install(ConfigApplier.java:108)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.SimpleConfiguratorImpl.applyConfiguration(SimpleConfiguratorImpl.java:129)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.SimpleConfiguratorImpl.applyConfiguration(SimpleConfiguratorImpl.java:143)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.Activator.start(Activator.java:48)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:936)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:319)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1562)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.startWorker(SystemModule.java:242)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.start(SystemModule.java:172)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:393)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:412)
at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.start(Equinox.java:115)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:320)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:232)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

There's not much information on the web what the problem is, most suggest to just delete the workspace, but for most it only happens when starting up Eclipse, not the final applications - nonetheless, I deleted workspaces and the runtime-folders. Nothing helps. The "error" gets thrown in the exported product as well, but as far as I can tell, everything still works as expected.

Is there a way to fix it? And if not, is there a way to just hide that stupid exception (disable logging for a moment, clearing the log, whatever, I'm not picky)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This looks like the framework start up starts simpleconfigurator which tries to start the framework again. The framework detects this recursion and throws an exception to escape it. The problem appears to be in simpleconfigurator attempting the start the framework which is starting it.

Comment: Not starting `org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator` prevents the error.

Comment: Delete that .log file and restart eclipse, It should start properly

Comment: Deleting the .lock file inside your workspace/.metadata/ folder worked for me.

Comment: Like Stefan S. i removed the value ....simpleconfigurator_.....jar@1\:start from line osgi.bundles in file config.ini. After that it worked.

Answer (score 21):

I solved problem by following these simple steps,

1. Go to your eclipse directory and open configuration directory.
2. open org.eclipse.osgi directory.
3. open .manager folder.
4. Delete .fileTableLock file.
5. Restart your eclipse.

Comment: My path was C:\Users\myuserid\.eclipse\org.eclipse.platform_4.6.3_1709980481_win32_win32_x86_64\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\.manager\.fileTableLock

Answer (score 8):

I faced same issue.Deleting the given .log file from configuration folder and restarting eclipse should resolve your problem.

Comment: Do you mean deleting the "`.log`" file, or the "_workspace_`/.metadata/.lock`" file?

Comment: @david, Yes, just by deleting the `.log` file.

Answer (score 5):

I use Red Hat Developer Studio 10.4 (Eclipse 4.6) and i tried use Eclipse Checkstyle plugin.

After install i restarted my IDE and received the crash notification.

I tried all suggestions but only when i delete a file called `framework.info.34` my problem was solved.

This file is in `%eclipse_home%/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Issue pop-up after upgrading eclipse neon through update-site along with installation of some new plugins.

Step 01:
I removed .fileTable.* lock files from ${eclipse_home}/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/.manager directory.

Step 02:
Removed osgi cache and other plugins cache by starting in eclipse clean mode

eclipse -clean

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue,

i removed the files from respective places
1) "eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi.manager" 
.fileTableLock
.fileTable3
.fileTable4

2) eclipse\configuration
*.log

after that i opened the eclipse, it worked with out any restart of PC.

Answer (score 0):

for people that have this problem until runing eclipse in runtime from eclipse :
clean folder :
[yourEclipseSourceWorkspace]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/[yourRunConfiguration]/org.eclipse.osgi/.manager
[yourEclipseSourceWorkspace]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/[yourRunConfiguration]/org.eclipse.osgi remove all files (not folder)
then add to your configuration -clean as programm arg

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple. Just start your eclipse in clean mode.

1. Find location of "eclipse.exe" file. (Let's assume : C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe )
2. Go to `run` command (Windows+R)
3. Enter [location] +[space][-]clean

   Ex: C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe -clean

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue . Remove the .fileTableLock from "eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi.manager" and restart eclipse . It works .